# Probability of policyholder having exact $n$ accidents given Poisson dist. with parameter $\lambda$ distributed $f(\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}$

Tags: probability

An insurance company estimates that the probability of the number of accidents occurring every year of each of its policyholders ($x=1,2,...$) is:

$P[X=x]=\frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$,

where $\lambda>0$ depends on each policyholder's behavior. Tha company also estimates that the parameter $\lambda$ of a policyholder chosen randomly is a random variable whose densitu function is:

$f(\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}$.

The question is: compute the probability that the policyholder chosen randomly has $n$ accidents next year?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is actually the *conditional* probability mass of $X$ given $\Lambda=\lambda$ and the marginal probability density of $\Lambda$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}n\mid\Lambda{=}\lambda) & = \frac{\lambda^n \mathsf e^{-\lambda}}{n!} \mathbf 1_{n\in\Bbb N^+} \\[2ex] f_\Lambda(\lambda) & = \lambda\mathsf e^{-\lambda}\;\mathbf 1_{\lambda\in\Bbb R^+}\end{align}$$

And you want to find $\mathsf P(X{=}n)$, the *marginal* probability mass of $X$.

Can you do this now?

---

- Find the joint probability function of $X,\Lambda$
- Find the marginal probability function of $X$

Comment: Nope, it's not quite clear to met yet.

Comment: Which part?  First find the joint probability, then find the marginal from that.